# Google drive direct(raw) link to download image file

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I need to feed image into printing company. For that I need direct image link. Is it possible to get the link that, if used by curl immediately return content of the file.

For example, I have shared file
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B_dyDrMQHCjHMjF6LVpTRGRwSFk
is it possible to get a link which would, when used with

```
curl <something>?id=0B_dyDrMQHCjHMjF6LVpTRGRwSFk
```

which, when run, will produce

```
/*
Firebase Authentication Working Example, JavaScript, CSS, and HTML 
crafted with love and lots of coffee.
*/
html body {
```

etc.
I have an image file, this ccs file is just an example, but I can't find a way to get it work.
There are webcontent and webview link properties for file, but neither of them seem to do the trick.

Anyone know the solution/workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the php, you can use [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) for REST API:

> The Drive API allows you to download files that are stored in Google Drive. Also, you can download exported versions of Google Documents (Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, etc.) in formats that your app can handle. Drive also supports providing users direct access to a file via the URL in the **`webViewLink`** property.
>
> Depending on the type of download you'd like to perform — a file, a Google Document, or a content link — you'll use one of the following URLs:
>
> - Download a file — [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) with **`alt=media`** [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)
> - Download and export a Google Doc — [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)
> - Link a user to a file — **`webContentLink`** from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

To download files, you make an authorized **`HTTP GET`** request to the file's [resource URL](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) and include the query parameter **`alt=media`**

Here is a sample code for PHP:

```
$fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
$response = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
    'alt' => 'media'));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Hope this helps.